# Getting entities by ID returns 'datastore: no such entity'

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to pass the entity ID by URL and then get the entity of that ID.
Here is my code.

```
// returns the common key for all users
func usersKey(c appengine.Context) *datastore.Key {
    return datastore.NewKey(c, "User", "default_user", 0, nil)
}

func RegisterHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    // ... validations bla bla
    u := User{Email: email, Hash: hash, Joined: time.Now()}
    key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "User", usersKey(c))
    if _, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &u); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func ProfileHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    params := mux.Vars(r)

    key := datastore.NewKey(c, "User", params["id"], 0, usersKey(c))
    u := new(User)
    if err := datastore.Get(c, key, u); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
}
```

Tthe `params["id"]` is correct. But the `datastore.Get` returns always an error: `datastore: no such entity`

Comment: If the entity has a auto generated id, then is needs to be an int, not a string.  Also if the entity was created with an ancestor that needs to be included when creating the key.

Comment: Thanks, I passed the ID as an int and it works now.

Comment: getting the same error, but the solution doesn't work for me (I have a string ID). drives me nuts ('datastore: no such entity' is completely unrelated...)

Comment: @orcaman, show some code :)